# Why does popup disappears in second

Tags: javascript

I have created a form (in PHP) where a user input data and click submit button.
here I have programmed js for a popup on click of 'submit' button.

Popup gets load properly but gets disappeared in half of the second.

Where do I go wrong? the js is as follows:

```
var popupStatus = 0;

function loadPopup() {
    if (popupStatus == 0) {
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        });
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}

function disablePopup() {
    //disables popup only if it is enabled
    if (popupStatus == 1) {
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}

function centerPopup() {

    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
    var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();

    $("#popupContact").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight / 2 - popupHeight / 2,
        "left": windowWidth / 2 - popupWidth / 2
    });
    $("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });

}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Submit").click(function() {
        //centering with css
        centerPopup();
        //load popup
        loadPopup();
    });


    $("#popupContactClose").click(function() {
        disablePopup();
    });

    $("#backgroundPopup").click(function() {
        disablePopup();
    });

    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27 && popupStatus == 1) {
            disablePopup();
        }
    });

});
```

Above code works fine in HTML but it goes crazy with PHP.

please help

Comment: are you using form post in your html? something like `<form action="action_page.php" method="post">`

Comment: yes i am doing it. but not to any page but as [action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" ] as i update data in database through this form.

Comment: In that case, `#Submit` doesnt care about what's happending on the javascript, it will submit anyway, unless you stop it (e.g `return false;`), but i do not think you want to do that, My suggestion would be to have a hidden extra button that you will use for your popup check

Comment: You have to stop the form from submitting!!

Answer (score 0):

To handle this, you can create an extra hidden button next to your submit button, this will be used for your popup check:

```
<!--Hide YOUR ORIGINAL Button-->  
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Submit" style="display:none">    
<input type="Submit" id="FakeSubmit" value="Submit">
```

In your javascript write load your popup in the `FakeSubmit` button event(this button does not submit):

```
$("#FakeSubmit").click(function(){
    //centering with css
    centerPopup();
    //load popup
    loadPopup();
 });
```

After all your popup checks, auto-submit your form by triggering your submit button:

```
 $("#Submit").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally what you need to do is to prevent the form from submitting on clicking the submit button, and after you have validated the form, submit the form. It should be somewhat similar to the following:

```
$("#Submit").click(function() {
        //centering with css
        centerPopup();
        //load popup
        loadPopup();

        // prevent form from submitting
        return false;
});

// validation function
$('#OKButton').click(function() {
     //form by id
     $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

Hope this helps.